# PHPMyAdmin Foreign Key Error - failed to add constraint

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

I am trying to design a database structure for my home budget app in PHP.
While setting up foreign keys I bumped into a problem.

I have 3 tables:

log (id, date, tranTypeID, categoryID, description, value, isForecast)
cateogry (id, categoryName)
transactiontype(id, transactionTypeName)

log - main budget record
category - list of fixed categories for the log records
transactiontype - holds just 2 records at the moment: expense, income

I set up foreign key for tranTypeID without a failure. When trying do the same for categoryID by:

```
ALTER TABLE `log` ADD  CONSTRAINT `fk_log_category` FOREIGN KEY (`categoryID`) REFERENCES `category`(`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

I am getting a following error:

> ## 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`budget`.`#sql-1aac_349`, CONSTRAINT `fk_log_category` FOREIGN KEY (`categoryID`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`))

I did set up all table engines to InnoDB and all the related columns has exact same data type set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are that there are records in your `log` table whose `categoryID` does not exist in the `cateogry` table. You would need to update or delete these records before creating the foreign key.

You can use the below query to find the offending records :

```
SELECT DISTINCT categoryID 
FROM log l LEFT JOIN category c ON c.id = l.categoryID
WHERE c.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: I thouth this would be a case before, but I simply deleted all records from log table as it was just just 3 rows. The log table at the moment is empty

Comment: @RobertJamborski : mm... could you please update your question and add the descriptions of both tables, like the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE ?